# How could I span the dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

This is my current dropdown

[image: inline]

I want to make the dropdown menu be spanned like this

[image: inline]

I'm using this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2 to build my dropdown

- AngularJS
- JQuery
- Select2

I have no idea that if there is any option can span the dropdown menu.

any keyword to search the related information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can expand the `select` element's dropdown to create that effect. To achieve this you will have to first create a textbox instead of dropdown. Next, you will have to create a `div` and place it right below the text box. On the click of textbox show the div which will serve as suggestions.

[See this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNEZPv)

I don't know jQuery or Angular, so I designed this in plain Javascript but the example will give you a fair idea to start.

**Disadvantages:** This will not serve as search box. User will have to select the option from the dropdown (unlike dropdown in which user can search based on keystrokes).

Search like functionality can be achieved by further the extending the code and recreating the suggestions div on each and every keystroke.

You will have to style the text box to show it like a dropdown.

**Tip:** You can inspect the website of your competitor and see if it is a drop down or something. Use developer tools to inspect elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it seems the overhead is too heavy to do that ~~ thank you